# crone tab shell script do not save output

Tags: shell

i use cron tab with command

```
wget http://www.mydomain.com/page.php
```

to run one of my pages in server. It works, but problem is output is sved with names
page.php,
page.php1,
page.php2,
page.php3
etc. 
Can i run the page using wget without sving output

Answer (score 2):

try

```
wget http://www.mydomain.com/page.php -O /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

`wget -O - http://mydomain.com/page.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

You need to specify `-O -` to output to STDOUT, then use `> /dev/null` to route STDOUT to the null